# How to implement template specialization like this?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Now, the function 'JoinStrings' I use can only join data type std::string. I need to join integer now. So I hope to refactor it. But I failed. I am glad to hear "you cannot do it in this way", because I really don't know whether it is reasonable to reuse these codes in this way or not.

The invoking part:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
      vector<int> integers;
      string str = JoinStrings(integers);
      cout << str << endl;
}
```

---

The part I failed to implement:

```
#include <string>

template <class ConstForwardIterator>
void JoinStrings(const ConstForwardIterator& begin,
                 const ConstForwardIterator& end,
                 const std::string& delimiter,
                 std::string* output) {
  output->clear();
  for (ConstForwardIterator iter = begin; iter != end; ++iter) {
    if (iter != begin) {
      output->append(delimiter);
    }   
    output->append(*iter);
  }
}

// What data type should be declared for IntegerConstForwardIterator?
template<>
void JoinStrings(const IntegerConstForwardIterator& begin,
                 const IntegerConstForwardIterator& end,
                 const std::string& delimiter,
                 std::string* output) {
  output->clear();
  for (IntegerConstForwardIterator iter = begin; iter != end; ++iter) {
    if (iter != begin) {
      output->append(delimiter);
    }   
    output->append(std::to_string(*iter));
  }
}

template <class ConstForwardIterator>
std::string JoinStrings(const ConstForwardIterator& begin,
                        const ConstForwardIterator& end,
                        const std::string& delimiter) {
  std::string output;
  JoinStrings(begin, end, delimiter, &output);
  return output;
}

template <class Container>
std::string JoinStrings(const Container& container,
                        const std::string& delimiter = " ") {
  return JoinStrings(container.begin(), container.end(), delimiter);
}
```

Comment: failed how? did you get compiler errors or unexpected behavior?

Comment: Intuitively, I'd suggest that you don't use `std::string` to generate the output, but `std::ostringstream`. This would solve many problems -- in particular, you wouldn't even need a specialization of the template for `int` any more.

Comment: OK, I'm trying. By the way, Is there any efficiency lost?

Comment: @Mou it depends what you're using it for. I'd say negligible. Profile and see.

Comment: @mou workimg correct easy to understand code first.  Make it faster only once you have mastered that, because many pieces of code do not need speed, and much speed has been written at the cost of bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to modify the code to achieve what you want. I interpret this question as a template specialization exercise. (For a recommended alternative, follow jogojapan's comment)

**Foreword:** I was expecting this to work, but (although it compiles) it doesn't because the generic version is still a better match:

```
template<template <class> class Cont >
void JoinStrings(const typename Cont<int>::const_iterator& begin,
                 const typename Cont<int>::const_iterator& end,
                 const std::string& delimiter,
                 std::string* output) {
    std::clog << "specialized called" << std::endl;
    ....
}
```

So, I had to resort to the good old `enable_if` (I use c++11 for brevity here, with some effort can be made into C++98). With your `main` code the specialized version will be called.

**Solution**

```
#include<type_traits>
....
template <class ConstForwardIterator, 
    class = typename std::enable_if<not std::is_same<typename std::decay<decltype(*std::declval<ConstForwardIterator>())>::type, int>::value>::type
>
void JoinStrings(const ConstForwardIterator& begin,
                 const ConstForwardIterator& end,
                 const std::string& delimiter,
                 std::string* output) {
    std::clog << "generic called" << std::endl;
    std::clog << std::trace() << std::endl;
}

template <class ConstForwardIterator, 
    class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::decay<decltype(*std::declval<ConstForwardIterator>())>::type, int>::value>::type,
    class Tag = void
>
void JoinStrings(const ConstForwardIterator& begin,
                 const ConstForwardIterator& end,
                 const std::string& delimiter,
                 std::string* output) {
    std::clog << "special called" << std::endl;
    ....
}
```

**A more classic solution** is to use "Tag dispatching" http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#tag_dispatching, but that requieres to change more code like your Container-version of JoinString.

**Restricted solution:** In case you are expecting the code to work only with `std::vector` the solution is much simpler:

```
template <>
void JoinStrings(const std::vector<int>::const_iterator& begin,
                 const std::vector<int>::const_iterator& end,
                 const std::string& delimiter,
                 std::string* output)
```

Comment: OK, I'm glad to hear that. Your point is refactoring like this is not reseanable or not practical.

Comment: @Mou, I didn't try to make any point. Just tried to write something that looks like a specialization.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? As @jogojapan said, using std::ostringstream is a better choice.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template <class ConstForwardIterator>
std::string JoinStrings(const ConstForwardIterator& begin,
        const ConstForwardIterator& end,
        const std::string& delimiter) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    for (ConstForwardIterator iter = begin; iter != end; ++iter) {
        if (iter != begin) {
            oss << delimiter;
        }
        oss << *iter;
    }
    return oss.str();
}

template <class Container>
std::string JoinStrings(const Container &container,
        const std::string& delimiter = " ") {
    return JoinStrings(container.begin(),
            container.end(), delimiter);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> integers;
    integers.push_back(1);
    integers.push_back(2);
    integers.push_back(3);
    std::string str = JoinStrings(integers);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    strings.push_back("MOU");
    strings.push_back("BI");
    str = JoinStrings(strings);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not I need. What I need is "not reasonable" or "type of IntegerConstForwardIterator" but the functional implemention in another way.